# How to get a value of a variable from other Component when value is initialized on runtime?

Tags: angular

i want to get a value from a Variable, which is on another Component and the value defines when i select something.

My Code from first Class:

```
selectedStartLocation: Location;
selectedDestLocation: Location;
```

html:

```
  <mat-form-field class="startLocation">
<input matInput placeholder="Abflughafen" aria-label="startLocations" [matAutocomplete]="autoForStart" [(ngModel)]="selectedStartLocation" name="airport" (keyup)="getStartLocations()">
<mat-autocomplete #autoForStart="matAutocomplete">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let location of startLocations" [value]="location.airPortName">
    <span>{{location.airPortName}}</span>
    <small>Kürzel: {{location.acronym}}</small>
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Second Class:

```
dateRange = new Dates;
```

And the other Component where i want to use them:

```
@Component({
  providers: [DateComponent, LocationComponent],
  selector: 'app-flight-service',
  templateUrl: './flight-service.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./flight-service.component.css']
})
export class FlightServiceComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() date: DateComponent;
  @Input() locations: LocationComponent;

  constructor(private locationService: LocationService,
              private datePipe: DatePipe) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public setFlight() {
    let fromDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.date.dateRange.from, 'dd.MM.yyyy');
    let toDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.date.dateRange.to, 'dd.MM.yyyy');
    return this.locationService.setFlightsForSelectedLocations(this.locations.selectedStartLocation, this.locations.selectedDestLocation,
      fromDate, toDate).subscribe(value => {
      this.locations.selectedStartLocation = value;
      this.locations.selectedDestLocation = value;
      fromDate = value;
      toDate = value;
    });
  }
}
```

I tried Input and declerations for them like Input() date: DateComponent or in Constructor: private date: DateComponent but everytime the value is undefined or null.But if i try it in the own class the value is correct. Can Someone Help me?

Comment: How are your two components connected to each other? Please post some more code.

Comment: @fridoo edited:)

Comment: It's still not fully clear to me how your components interact. Is one the parent component and the other the child component? Or are they siblings and have a third parent component? How is FlightServiceComponent used in your app? How is the other (first) component used? Could you post more code of the first component and code of the component where the first and second component are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [this](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) scheme, which is component interaction via service.

In general, your service should be a model(date keeper) and your components should be subscribed to its changes, so when you change something from one component, other one will definitely know about it.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to pass the value to the component. For example, if you declare in the component `my-component`:

```
Input() date: DateComponent
```

Your html should include the input as:

```
<my-component date=dateToUse />
```